# Do we have a call back method or event listener for sftp-Input adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration-sftp

I am using sftp input adapter & Post polling file to local, I want to read the content and implement some logic. Is there a call back function available with sftp inbound-channel-adapter?
I am new to spring so please share the option available to process the file post successful polling.

config:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
            auto-startup="true"
            channel="receiveChannel"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            remote-directory="/home/sftp/source"
            local-directory="file:/home/sftp/target/"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            filename-regex=".*\.txt$">
<int:poller fixed-rate="5000" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I don't see any call back method which will get invoked every time the file is polled. Intention is to poll the file from source after fixed interval, read the content and perform some logic.
Java code snippet:

```
localFileChannel = context.getBean("receiveChannel", PollableChannel.class);

SessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory = context.getBean(CachingSessionFactory.class);

template = new RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry>(sessionFactory);

SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = context.getBean(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
            adapter.start();

Message<?> received = (Message<?>) localFileChannel.receive(1000);
```

Comment: Could you add some code to understand your question better?

Comment: Thanks!! GROX13 ..i have edited the question for better understanding